# What letters should I get from my employer to show my contract job experience?

Tags: job-change, work-experience, contracts, job-description, recommendation-letter

I do a lot of contract work. What letters should I get from my clients, other than MoU and invoice, which would serve me as **proof** of my experience for future jobs?

Comment: Edited the title to match the question in the body of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the MOUs include a listing of your deliverables and the listing is explicit and specific enough, this should be enough proof that you know what you are trading in - You'd have been out of a contract if you had failed to deliver.

If you have your own website - you could create one for yourself for free on say tumblr.com, you could include some testimonials from the clients (cite the name and the company on the page but leave out their contact info) you worked with about the specific skilled tasks you accomplished for them and how well you came through. And now that I think about it, LinkedIn also gives you the ability to post these client testimonials.

Comment: Gr8 one take client testimonial try to get it over his letter head.Website testimonials are great too but so many fakes have maligned their reputation a bit.

Comment: @amar The website testimonials would be extracted from written testimonials on the clients' letterheads :) Thank you for your input :)